# Saving data in vertical column format in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to save the list `Mean1` in vertical column format. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
Mean1= [25.482954545454543,
 9.914772727272727,
 5.369318181818182,
 4.545454545454545,
 4.318181818181818,
 4.176136363636363,
 4.119318181818182,
 4.090909090909091,
 4.0625,
 4.0625]

with open('Mean.csv', 'w+') as f: 
    
        f.write(f"Mean1 = {str(Mean1)}\n")
```

The current output is

[image]

The expected output is

[image]

Comment: CSV is just a text file. What you posted is *not* a text file. What does the *text file* look like? BTW what you wrote isn't a CSV file either. A CSV has an optional header row and data rows with Values Separated by Commas. The very fact there's ` Mean = ....` means you just have a text file, not a CSV

Comment: Python has a built-in [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). Pandas has `to_csv` and `read_csv` methods. There's no need to do this manually. CSV is just text *but* there are some quirks, like allowing newlines in quoted fields. Try using a [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) and `writerow` and let the module deal with escaping, formatting, etc.

Comment: BTW the code you wrote doesn't even try to store any data in rows. `str(Mean1)` returns the string representation of an object, not rows.   Try writing `print(Mean1)`. Or `print(str(Mean1))`. That's never going to produce any newlines.

Comment: Why are you using `w+` mode if you are just writing?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are right. I want to produce new lines and store each element as shown in the expected output. I tried using ```print(Mean1)```  and ```print(str(Mean1))``` but doesn't help.

Comment: You missed the point. What you tried to do will never work. You aren't writing any lines. `print(Mean1)` shows why your attempt is wrong. Did you check the `csv` module link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
import csv

Mean1= [25.482954545454543,
 9.914772727272727,
 5.369318181818182,
 4.545454545454545,
 4.318181818181818,
 4.176136363636363,
 4.119318181818182,
 4.090909090909091,
 4.0625,
 4.0625]

Mean1 = [[e] for e in Mean1]

with open(r'path_to_your_outputCsv.csv', 'w', newline="\n") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerow(['Mean1'])
    wr.writerows(Mean1)
```

Or, if you're fine with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), you can store the elements of a list (each in one separated row) in a `.csv` by using [**`pandas.DataFrame`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) and [**`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) combined.

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

Mean1= [25.482954545454543,
 9.914772727272727,
 5.369318181818182,
 4.545454545454545,
 4.318181818181818,
 4.176136363636363,
 4.119318181818182,
 4.090909090909091,
 4.0625,
 4.0625]

pd.DataFrame(Mean1, columns=['Mean1']).to_csv(r'path_to_your_outputCsv.csv', index=False)
```